# Contact form is not being translated

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n, emails

I have a multilingual Drupal 7 site with following languages enabled:

- Dutch (default)
- French

Now when I enable my sitewide contact form, and navigate to it using Dutch (http://www.mywebsite.com/nl/contact) it is in Dutch (as it should be).

However, when I navigate to what is supposed to be the French version (using http://www.mywebsite.com/fr/contact), it shows me the English contact form ...

I have downloaded & imported the French `.po` file for the contact form to no avail , the contact form stays in English.

Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `.po`-files, install the [Localization Update](http://drupal.org/project/l10n_update) module.  It provides a much better interface for downloading, updating and managing translations.

Comment: good solution for me, tnx ,I have a probelem,I translate manually  content type  name but in content management page the type of them  not translated !!!

Comment: Hey @Free_Radical ... refer to my answer to this question to understand that I think l10n_update is not going to help to answer the question here. Curious to hear if you'll agree, or have a different viewpoint. No need for "Mea Culpa" though ...

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens, this question is 2.5 years old, and the OP never gave any feedback. However, to me it looks like the OP is not getting French language installed, and **Localization update** will help with that. To switch languages, I rely on **Content translation** (in core). I have *never* needed any of the [**i18n**](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n)-submodules to get language-switching working with D7, but maybe the contact form is special? I've tried to enable **i18n** - and I immediately experience translation quirks, so I never use it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Interesting to know you get along with hardly any i18n stuff (i always use quite a few of them). Looks like you "interprete" the question different from how I understand it. Let's wait & see if the OPer ever comes back to it again ...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you install the [Localization Client](https://www.drupal.org/project/l10n_client) module as this will help in other translations also.

After installing, when you go to the French contact form (or any other French page), you will see the in-page translation interface at the bottom of the page. Just search for the terms like "Your name", put the French translations and save. Reload the page and you should see the translations.

Comment: The Localization Client module works only with JQuery 1.7 without destroying my bootstrap theme's styling. Whenever I need to translate stuff, I switch to 1.7 and then back to 1.9 for other modules to function properly

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the 'Contact Translation' (i18n_contact) sub-module of [i18n](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n) is enabled.

If you then navigate to admin/structure/contact and use the "edit" link for any of the available categories, you'll also have a "Translate" tab.

This tab can be used for translating the "*Category*" in the selected langusage, and to translate the "*Auto-reply*" for that language.

Refer to https://www.drupal.org/node/1396984 for more detailed (Community) documentation.

**Note**: the [Localization Client](https://www.drupal.org/project/l10n_client) and [Localization Update](https://www.drupal.org/project/l10n_update) modules (suggested in the other answers) are great modules, but they serve a different purpose. They won't help to make the French version of the form show up (instead of the English version of it).