# How to put conditional multiple recipients in drupal 7 default contact us form

Tags: i18n-l10n, emails

I am working on a multilingual Drupal 7 site using a single contact us form. It has 4 languages. The contact us form is multilingual i.e labels of form fields changes, depending on the language you have selected. But it has a single recipient now.

Now I want it to have conditional recipients i.e if English is selected the contact us form should be emailed to a@gmail.com and if Danish is selected then to b@gmail.com and so on.

Any suggestions how to do it ?

website form : http://dev-salman.com/venuepoint/contact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to my answer to the question "[Contact form is not being translated](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/38418/contact-form-is-not-being-translated/164288#164288)" related to the usage of the i18n_contact module. That's a prerequisite for the contact form to be available in multiple languages. However it will not allow you to specify an eMail ID for each language.

I'm not familiar (yet) with the [tContact](https://www.drupal.org/project/tcontact) module, but it might help to implement what you're trying to setup. Here's an excerpt about it (from its project page):

> ... allows you to make the site-wide contact form fully translated on multilingual sites. Categories can be set to display only in a specific language, or they can be language neutral. Depends on the core "contact" module for the site wide contact form.

If with the [tContact](https://www.drupal.org/project/tcontact) module you still can't get it to work, then I'd investigate if sending eMails by using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module you can get it to work. E.g. by using the patch in [comment #3](https://www.drupal.org/node/1472316#comment-5721784) of [issue # 1472316](https://www.drupal.org/node/1472316). For more details about this issue, visit the question about  "[Rule condition to check which language is used by the visitor?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/23820/rule-condition-to-check-which-language-is-used-by-the-visitor)".

Answer (score 0):

With this module https://www.drupal.org/project/tcontact you can create different contact categories for each language so you can specific different recipients.